# To compute the worst-case running time function of an algorithm what are the steps to be followed? Algorithms

Tags: algorithm

To compute the worst-case running time function of an algorithm what are the steps to be followed? Please some one guide me in that. I think these steps includes some mathematical proof's. If I am correct In which parts of mathematics areas I should be strong? (I guess mathematical Induction,functions, sets are enough)

Thanks

Comment: @Pete: there's more than one country in the world.

Comment: I think http://cstheory.stackexchange.com/ is the more appropriate place for this question.

Comment: @Elaffer: the people at cstheory don't want to be bothered with freshman questions. They only accept research-level stuff.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can find good answers in the following books:

- http://www.algorist.com/
- "Art of computer programming", Knuth

I think mostly this is: good understanding of the algorithm, combinatorics and computational complexity theory - http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Computational_complexity_theory

Answer (score 0):

To learn about computational complexity you need to know Calculus, Combinatorics, Set Theory, Summations amongst other maths topics.

A good book; though fairly theoretical is [Introduction To Algorithms](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0262032937) by Cormen et. al.